# NoNodeAvailableException when trying to connect to ES hosted on AWS

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have an ES instance running on AWS and I wish to connect to it using the JAVA API.

```
TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().build()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9320));

List<DiscoveryNode> nodes = client.connectedNodes();

System.out.println(nodes.size()); // prints 0

for (DiscoveryNode node : nodes) {
  System.out.println(node.toString());
}

SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("indexName");

String postQuery = "{ some stuff }";

searchRequestBuilder.setQuery(QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(postQuery));

SearchResponse searchResponse = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
System.out.println(searchResponse.toString().replace("\n\n", "\n"));
```

When I run this program I get:

> NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available:
>    [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9320}]

I have tunnelled into the instance where the TCP port is `9320` and REST port is `9220`.

```
animesh$ lsof -i :9320
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ssh     44239 animesh    7u  IPv6 ______ 0t0  TCP localhost:9320 (LISTEN)
ssh     44239 animesh    8u  IPv4 ______ 0t0  TCP localhost:9320 (LISTEN)

animesh$ curl localhost:9220
{
  "name" : "SuperNode",
  "cluster_name" : "SuperCluster",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.0",
    "build_hash" : "8371be8d5fe5df7fb9c0516c474d77b9feddd888",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-03-29T07:54:48Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try with 9220?

Comment: That is for HTTP calls. `TransportClient` requires the TCP connection

Comment: Are the client and server versions same?

Comment: Yes, I have ES 2.3.0 and Lucene 5.5.0 in my POM file

Comment: Do you have a custom cluster name?

Comment: The cluster on AWS is named `SuperCluster`. I don't know if I need to specify it in the program?

Comment: Checkout second example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html#transport-client

Answer (score 0):

My checkout list for this case is:

- The client and server versions can be different
- Cluster name can be different
- There could be a network problem when accesing the host and port.